# Process for solving this system of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, circles, tangent-line

I have this system of equations for which I'd like to solve for $x$,$y$, and $r$ where $a$,$b$, and $t$ are constants:

1: $0 = (x-a)^2 + (y - b)^2 - t^2$

2: $y = \dfrac{bx-rx+ar}{a}$

3: $r = \dfrac{x^2 + y^2}{2y}$

Could anyone help me get a point where one of $x$,$y$, or $r$ are defined in terms of $a$,$b$, and $t$?

I know this system is solvable in the reals (for some values of $a$,$b$, and $t$) , for example: [a = 80 b = 100 t = 60](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2)%2F%20(2y)%20%3D%20r%20;%200%20%3D%20(x-a)%5E2%20%2B%20(y-b)%5E2%20-%20t%5E2;%20y%20%3D%20(bx-rx%2Bar)%2Fa;%20a%20%3D%2080;%20b%20%3D%20100;%20t%20%3D%2060%20solve%20for%20r), but I am unsure how WA is doing the steps of manipulation to solve.

Essentially the problem is given a circle centered at $(a,b)$ with radius $t$, find a circle which is tangent to the x-axis at $(0,0)$ and the other circle at some point $(x,y)$.

Equation 1 is simply the equation of the original circle.

Since it is tangent to the x-axis it must be of the form $x^2 + y^2 - 2ry = 0$ where $r$ is the radius, which is where the above equation 3 comes from.

To obey tangency between the two circles, the slope from $(0,r)$ to $(a,b)$ must be the same slope as from $(0,r)$ to $(x,y)$ which is the source of equation 2.

Any insight or recommendations are greatly appreciated.

Edit: Oversight from before, tangent at (0,0)

Comment: There seems to be something missing from your description of the original problem that you’re trying to solve. Given a circle, there are an infinite number of circles that are tangent to both it and the $x$-axis.

Comment: Correct, I am missing the fact that it must intersect at (0,0). Will update

Comment: So, the second circle’s center lies on the $y$-axis, yes?

Comment: Good catch by the way @amd

Comment: Correct, which is where the $x^2 + y^2 - 2ry = 0$ equation is derived from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d like to offer a perhaps simpler solution to the original problem.

The point of tangency of the two circles lies on the line through their centers. The distance between their centers is equal to either the sum or difference of their radii. The center of a tangent circle will be at either $(x_c,y_c)=(0,r)$, $(0,-r)$ or both. After working through all of the possible sign combinations we’re left with two equations: $$(y_c\pm t)^2 = a^2+(y_c-b)^2.$$ These are linear equations for $y_c$ that give $$y_c={a^2+b^2-t^2\over2(b\pm t)}.$$ Similar triangles then yield $$x={y_c\over y_c\pm t}a \\ y=y_c+{y_c\over y_c\pm t}(b-y_c),$$ where in each of the two solutions $t$ has the same sign throughout.

Comment: This is only true if the circles are externally tangent. I am attempting to obtain answers for both internally and externally tangent circles. I could potentially use this for a case-wise solution. Thanks

Comment: @mascoj Nope. This solution holds generally if you interpret a negative radius as internal tangency.

Comment: @mascoj Indeed, I find it somewhat curious that all of the externally tangent circles have centers above the $x$-axis and internally tangent ones, below.

Comment: You can have both with positive radii. The example link I provided in my question results in radii of 40 and 160. I would comment with a tikz picture but SE doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: [Example image](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2+-+2*160*y+%3D+0;+x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2+-+2*40*y+%3D+0;+(x+-+80)%5E2+%2B+(y+-+100)%5E2+%3D+60%5E2)

Comment: @mascoj D’oh! I left out one of the solutions. No wonder the cases split between positive and negative $y$ so neatly. Answer updated. It agrees with your test case.

Answer (score 1):

$(3)\iff (\;(y\ne 0)\land (r^2=x^2+ (y-r)^2)\;).$ Subtracting this from (1) yields a linear equation in $x, y$ (with the extra condition $y\ne 0$),which, with (2), is a system  of 2 linear equations in 2 variables.

Comment: How does subtracting $(r^2=x^2+ (y-r)^2)$ from $(1)$ give a linear equation? r is a variable here.

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

Substitute (3) into (2) and after some manipulation:
$$y = x * \frac{b \pm \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 - x^2}}{a+x}$$

Substitute that into (1) and after much more manipulation:
$$ x=  \frac{a^3 + ab^2 - at^2}{a^2 + b^2 \pm 2bt + t^2 }$$

Given $x$, $y$ and $r$ can be calculated by substitution.